# How can i disable all bottom navigation button for lockscreen..?

Tags: android, launcher, android-homebutton

I'm creating lock screen application. and all activity work perfectly, But when screen lock activity comes up on screen on, all Home and task navigation button works. Only back button is not working because I have return nothing in `onBackPressed()` method.

Now I don't know how to disable this navigation buttons to work in my lockscreen application.

I have tried this:

```
@Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

 if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)||(keyCode ==   KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER)||(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)||(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA)) {
    //this is where I can do my stuff
   return false;
}
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
//Do Code Here
// If want to block just return false
return false;
}
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
//Do Code Here
// If want to block just return false
return false;
}
```

But Only back button stops working all other remain as it is.

Comment: [Here's Google's own dev guide for hiding the navigation bar.](http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html)

Comment: i want to disable home and task buttons. is there any code to disable this buttons..?

Comment: It's the lock screen, just disable the entire navigation bar. There's no need for any of the buttons.

Comment: this is not usefull, Because its hide navigation bar for only one time and show navigation when user touch on the screen.

Comment: i am still waiting for answers...

Comment: well.. having same scenario but not found any way please share your solution if you have found! @hardwork